# Substrate purge-chain expects a spec file

Tags: parity, substrate

Working from a substrate-node-template generated with the tools at https://getsubstrate.io, I'm having trouble purging the chain.

According to [this tutorial](https://shawntabrizi.github.io/substrate-collectables-workshop/#/1/1.5-viewing-a-storage-mapping), the command

`./target/release/substrate-node-template purge-chain --dev`

Should work, but I get an error that seems to be looking for a spec file.

`Error: Error opening spec file: No such file or directory (os error 2)`

Since the tutorial made no mention of this, I'm confused and would appreciate any insight.

Comment: You tagged your question with `substrate`, would you be interested in a dedicated Stack Exchange Q&A site for Substrate, Polkadot, et al. -- check out the [Area51 Substrate Proposal](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/122626/substrate?referrer=NTUwMTkxYjJjOTJiNjE0YzMxYjgwMGNkZmFlYzdhZTczYjk1ZWY3ZGI4NzJmODUwN2RlYTQ2MTNjZTdkOTZhMAzuL-zybtPN9CHzwE-WUdvBC8WxvPG46b4ayadke6kG0)

Answer (score 3):

This is an expected behavior.

The `./target/release/substrate-node-template purge-chain --dev` command is a shortcut to delete a folder from your computer. If the folder does not exist, for example if you already deleted it, then you will get this error.

So you should be in a good spot to proceed here. BTW a more appropriate place to ask questions about the Substrate blockchain development framework built by Parity Technologies is here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/substrate